# Delete a string in a dictionary after it's shown

Tags: python, dictionary, repeat

I am trying to make a multiple choice quiz by using a dictionary. I have everything but it is repeating the same question it has been asked before. Should I use `popitem`, `pop` method, or something else?

```python
def German():
  import random
  a_q = {'Berlin':'What is east capital city for German?',
       'Bonn':'What is west capital city for German?',
       'Michael Schumacher':'What is a famous formula one driver?',
       'Albert Einstein':'He was one of the smartest one.'}
  keys = [x for x in random.sample(a_q, 3)]
  correctanswer = a_q[random.choice(keys)]
  correctanswer.popitems()
  print 'Question: ', correctanswer
  key1, key2, key3 = keys[0], keys[1], keys[2]
  print '\nA. %s \nB. %s \nC. %s' % (key1, key2, key3)
  A, B, C = a_q[key1], a_q[key2], a_q[key3]
  answer = raw_input('What is the right answer? ')

  if answer == "A":
        if A == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"
            German()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, that is incorrect"
            print('')
            German()

  elif answer == "B":
        if B == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"
            German()

        else:
            print "I'm sorry, that is incorrect"
            German()

  elif answer == "C":
        if C == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"
            German()
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, that is incorrect"
            German()

  else:
        print "That is not a valid selection."

German()
```

Comment: Use a loop and stop calling the function each time

Comment: Your function is recursive, so even if you delete an element from the dictionary, you're adding it again when the function is recalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the [comments of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899504/delete-a-string-in-a-dictionary-after-its-shown/29904095#comment47923346_29899504), your function was recursive, so even if you deleted an element from the dictionary, you'd re-add it when the function is recalled.

To fix this, you can use this line of code:

```
q = [x for x in random.sample(a_q, len(a_q))]
```

This creates a randomly ordered list of questions so you can iterate through without having any repeated questions. *This would also work no matter how many questions you add.*

Now, for the answers, you can use this piece of code:

```
c=random.sample(a_q, 3)
while c.count(q[i]) != 1:
    c=random.sample(a_q, 3)
random.shuffle(c)
```

This creates a random list of 3 answers with the correct answer shown as `q[i]`. The while loop is used to prevent any repeated answers in the answer pool.

If you put this together:

```
def German():
    import random
    a_q = {'Berlin':'What is east capital city for German?',
           'Bonn':'What is west capital city for German?',
           'Michael Schumacher':'What is a famous formula one driver?',
           'Albert Einstein':'He was one of the smartest one.',
           'The Berlin Wall':'What was the wall called that separated the country?',
           'Boris Becker':'He was a good tennis player he won two wimbildom titles?',
           '2006':'What year was the FIFA World Cup held in Germany?',
           '3':'How many world cups does Germany have?',
           'Yodeling':'What is one of the tradition in German?',
           '9 months':'How long does Zugspitze winter last for?'}

    q = [x for x in random.sample(a_q, len(a_q))] #create list of questions
    i=0 #start counter

    while i < len(q):                 #iterate through every question

        correctanswer = a_q[q[i]]     #define the correct answer
        print 'Question: ', correctanswer
        c=random.sample(a_q, 3)       
        while c.count(q[i]) != 1:
            c=random.sample(a_q, 3)   #get the answer pool
        key1, key2, key3 = c
        print '\nA. %s \nB. %s \nC. %s' % (key1, key2, key3)
        A, B, C = a_q[key1], a_q[key2], a_q[key3]
        answer = raw_input('What is the right answer? ')

        while answer not in 'ABCD':   #check for invalid inputs
             print "That is not a valid selection.\n"
             answer = raw_input('What is the right answer? ')

        if answer == 'A' and A  == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"
        elif answer == 'B' and B == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"          
        elif answer == 'C' and C == correctanswer:
            print "That's correct!"
        else:
            print "I'm sorry, that is incorrect"
        i+=1

German()
```

This would output:

```
>>> 
Question:  How many world cups does Germany have?

A. Bonn 
B. Yodeling 
C. 3
What is the right answer? 3
That is not a valid selection.

What is the right answer? C
That's correct!
Question:  What is one of the tradition in German?

A. Yodeling 
B. Boris Becker 
C. The Berlin Wall
What is the right answer? A
That's correct!
Question:  What year was the FIFA World Cup held in Germany?

A. Bonn 
B. Yodeling 
C. 2006
What is the right answer? C
That's correct!
Question:  How long does Zugspitze winter last for?

A. Albert Einstein 
B. Bonn 
C. 9 months
What is the right answer? C
That's correct!
Question:  What is east capital city for German?

A. Berlin 
B. 9 months 
C. Boris Becker
What is the right answer? A
That's correct!
Question:  He was one of the smartest one.

A. Albert Einstein 
B. The Berlin Wall 
C. 2006
What is the right answer? A
That's correct!
Question:  What is west capital city for German?

A. Bonn 
B. Yodeling 
C. 9 months
What is the right answer? B
I'm sorry, that is incorrect
Question:  What is a famous formula one driver?

A. Michael Schumacher 
B. The Berlin Wall 
C. Yodeling
What is the right answer? A
That's correct!
Question:  He was a good tennis player he won two wimbildom titles?

A. Bonn 
B. Berlin 
C. Boris Becker
What is the right answer? C
That's correct!
Question:  What was the wall called that separated the country?

A. Boris Becker 
B. The Berlin Wall 
C. Michael Schumacher
What is the right answer? B
That's correct!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# save the key you choose
k = random.choice(keys);

# store correct answer
correctanswer = a_q[k]

# remove question from dict
del correctanswer[k]
```

**Edit**: but you need to assign the dictionary outside the function

Comment: but correct answer[k] is a string object and I can't delete the string object. Thanks for helping me

Comment: The function is repeatedly called so the dict is always recreated so this willl not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep calling the function use a  loop, every time you call the function the dict is recreated so it is pointless trying to remove anything:

```
def German():
    import random

    a_q = {'Berlin': 'What is east capital city for German?',
           'Bonn': 'What is west capital city for German?',
           'Michael Schumacher': 'What is a famous formula one driver?',
           'Albert Einstein': 'He was one of the smartest one.'}

    samp = random.sample(a_q.items(), 3)
    qs = [v for _, v in samp]
    ans = [k for k, _ in samp]
    A, B, C = ans
    d = {"A": A,"B": B,"C": C}
    for a, q in zip(ans, qs):
        print 'Question: {}'.format(q)
        print '\nA. {} \nB. {} \nC. {}' .format(A, B, C)
        answer = raw_input('What is the right answer? ')
        # check answer against a
        if d[answer] == a:
            print("That is correct")
        else:
            print("Sorry that is incorrect")
```

Output:

```
Question:  What is a famous formula one driver?

A. Michael Schumacher 
B. Berlin 
C. Albert Einstein
What is the right answer? A
That's correct!
Question:  What is east capital city for German?

A. Michael Schumacher 
B. Berlin 
C. Albert Einstein
What is the right answer? B
That's correct!
Question:  He was one of the smartest one.

A. Michael Schumacher 
B. Berlin 
C. Albert Einstein
What is the right answer? C
That's correct!
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but if I missed a question it will still repeat the question it has been ask before? How should I do that?

Comment: use an inner while loop, how many times are you going to let a user try again considering there are only three possible answers?

Comment: only one time, actually my team and I are making a game by using pygame but the button is not working so I am trying to run it on the shell.

Comment: @LeoLai. this only asks each question once

Comment: Yeah, but It will stop when you chose the wrong answer, so I put German() after else. And It repeat the question again. What I want is even when you chose the wrong answer, you still can finish the quiz without repeating the same question. Thanks

Comment: @LeoLai. that is exactly what the code is doing, you get one shot at each  question

Comment: It stops after the third question.

Comment: you only have three questions in your sample so what do you expect?

Comment: I added to 10 questions in the dictionary!

Comment: Then if you want ten questions get 10 questions from the dict

Comment: I did, please look the code that I edit. I don't know whats wrong, but it still only show three questions

Comment: this is wrong `samp = random.sample(a_q.items(), 3)`, you are taking three elements from the dict so you get three elements, if you want 10 take ten

Comment: You have duplicate keys in your dict so that is not going to work

Comment: Obviously you also now also have more than A B and C so you cannot expect the code to work exactly like when you had three questions

Comment: I am sorry, can you explain more details for me please.

Comment: You need to read the code and understand what is happening, I have given you working code. If you add more questions to the dict and want to ask more questions then you need to change the code accordingly. How do you think `A, B, C = ans` is going to work if you have 5,6 10.. questions? Only you know how many questions you want to ask, the logic is exactly the same. You have use a sample size of 5 then you have five questions and answers so everything that was three is now 5